# Google Play Publish

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk, developer-console

Recentlly I have finished my first android game and put it in Google Play. I published it like 10 days ago but my game is still not visible if I search it by name. My game name is "Match It!" . I only can find it if I search "Match It! LCM" or using the link. What's the problem ? And why my app is not on "New & Updated Games" category ? And also, in Google Dev Console, at optimization tab , sais that the apk is not optimized for tablets and I have minimum api Level 11.  Here is my app link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.LCMGameStudios.MatchIt

Comment: About the optimization part, have you provided resources for tablets and different device screens? It might still take a while to have your application appear in search results because I know for certain there are a lot of game apps out there! Maybe give it some more time?

Comment: Yes . I tested it on 10 inch and 7 inch tablets and works perfect. No problem.. Everything is resizing without any problem. And about finding my app ... Can be any problem if my game name has the "!" in the name ? "Match It!"  ?

Comment: I really don't think it is the character in the name! How many people have downloaded your app? You see, the way search and popularity works is the same as in the regular Google Search - if more people search for something, it becomes "hot" and moves up the search index. Now, remember, app names matter - apps starting with letter A will always show up before those with M because users search using that pattern. I would give it time!

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices :D ! I will wait. Only 12 downloads. But is hard to promote an app with 0 money. So now the last problem is to find the problem with tablet optimization. "Your layout should make use of the available space on tablets", but my apk supports all screen sizes.

Comment: @Eenvincible to show as "optimized for tablets" one simply needs to upload tablet screenshots in the Google Play Developer Console

Comment: I uploaded. No problem with screenshoots.

Comment: c.f. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en section Screenshots

Comment: I know; I have done it several times before! It appears though that the OP doesn't have those screenshots for tablets

Comment: BTW your game does show up, just search for "Match It!" and check the **ninth** row of apps (on the desktop with 9 apps per row), it's just not as "important" as the other apps, that also match the search term

Comment: I still can't find my app by its name ... Only if I search "Match It! LCM" or "LCM Game Studios" ... Anyway. Thanks everyone for help :D ! If I will manage to resolve the tablets problem, I will post a reply

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while untill the google play search recognizes your app. When I uploaded my first app it took about 10 installs before it started showing up. If you search for your apps name and scroll down you will probably find it.

Keep in mind though that some apps with certain names can be "covered" by other apps with the same name/very similar names. When I search for your app, apps like match.com and match puzzle games appear. That is an initial problem that dissapears with time. The more installs you get with a specific search word, the more probable it is for your app to appear with the search "Match it!"

Some websites like https://www.mobileaction.co/ allows you to track the most commonly used search words to get to your app(I have barely used it so I don't really know if it tracks people who looks at the app but doesn't download it)

 If your phone isn't on the list of supported API's or devices, it probably won't show up. If it isn't optimized for tablets and you are on a tablet, you will still see it like any other user on a phone. The main difference between phone and tablet layouts can be shown here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have like 13 donwloads. But is hard to get downloads without money.

Comment: Money isn't a problem. Personally, I work alone and I have no funding what so ever and yet I have a total of 30 downloads on my first app and over 50 on my second. Getting the recognision is a problem, but google play has a category for new apps which allows for free adertising(not really advertising, but you get the point). Once you get a twitter account, facebok account you have free advertising. Once you get enough funding(or you push something into it yourself) and get a website, it is even more free advertising. Inside your apps remember to add contact info, as it will good coustomer

Comment: service is very important. Also keep in mind the layouts. Layouts is everything. If you have in app purchases, make sure the most expensive ones are better for the user to buy than several of the small ones. It is simple behaviour analytics, as it is cheaper in the long run to buy one big package once than several small packages several times.

Comment: Thank you for your advides :D Much appreciated :D !